# Typescript Unexpected token import mocha

Tags: node.js, typescript

I can't use imports because I always have this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { expect } from 'chai';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

In my file `index.test.ts` I have this:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
describe('Hello function', () => {
    it('should return hello world', () => {
        const result = hello();
        expect(result).to.equal('Hello World!');
    });
});
```

In my `package.json` I have this:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "mocha --reporter spec --compilers test/**/*.test.js",
```

},

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist",

    "strict": false
  }
}
```

Please tell me that how can I use imports?

Comment: Do you have a `.babelrc` file? If yes what does it have inside?

Comment: I do not have this file, I do not use babel.

Comment: which version of `mocha` are you using?

Comment: Mocha 5.2.0, @types/mocha  5.2.5

Comment: which version of Typescriptyou are using there are some issue with 2.0.0

Comment: Typescript 3.2:2,

Answer (score 3):

**mocha + typescript + es6 module**

1. tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

2. mocha.opts

```
--require ts-node/register
--require @babel/register
...
```

Comment: Please provide more than just code as an answer. Instead, an explanation of the code and a breakdown of why it answers the question is most beneficial.

Comment: Why is everyone *expecting* people use Babel? I'm using tsc, does that not work?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```sh
npx mocha --require ts-node/register --require esm src/**/*.spec.ts
```

Or in `package.json` scripts (both options work, choose whichever you like):

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r esm -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "test-ts": "ts-mocha -r esm -p tsconfig.json src/**/*.spec.ts"
}
```

And don't forget to add `esm` to `devDependencies`:

```
npm install --save-dev esm
```

so in package.json it is gonna be

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
}
```

P.S. Thanks @user318830, you made me realize it is possible to have several '--require' specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ./dev/ts-node-mocha/register-commonjs.js

require('ts-node').register({
    compilerOptions: {
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
});
```

`npx mocha --require ./dev/ts-node-mocha/register-commonjs --extensions ts  './src/**/*.spec.ts'`